# Changing an HTML value using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am having trouble changing the value of an html element. Here is the HTML element:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" onclick="click('button1')"/>
```

Here is my javascript function

```
function click(){
    document.getElementById("button1").value = "X";
  }
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include any errors seen in the console.

Comment: @Blauhirn Because the question isn’t easily answerable as it lacks a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a specific problem statement.

Comment: @Xufox it's not my question, but thanks. 2 downvotes because you can't just paste&copy OP's code sample? Why would that be necessary, not to speak of that the "problem" will be easily detectable anyway? (3 lines of code)

Comment: but I see, a proper error statement is missing. would it have beeen enough if DBL had said "nothing happens"?

Comment: @Blauhirn No, the code can’t be simply copied, as JS and HTML heavily depend on nesting, order and several other details. A specific problem statement is complete if it contains the desired behavior and a specific description of what didn’t work. In this case the problem was the redeclaration of `window.click` where DBL shouldn’t have used the name `click` for his function or used `addEventListener` instead of inline handlers. However, if there was an additional problem with code order, DBL would simply say that that didn’t work and no one knew why.

Comment: @Xufox — `window.click` hasn't been redeclared, the problem is that `document.getElementById("button1").click` masked it. The code (in *any* order) executes without any errors at all. The cause of the problem only begins to reveal itself if you use `console.log(click)` inside the `onclick` function or run a debugger there. There is very little that could be done to make the question better. Describing the approaches used to debug it might have helped, but it's clearly a beginner's question so familiarity with such techniques (especially the advanced ones needed *here*) shouldn't be expected

Comment: @Quentin I meant redefinition. At least that’s what JSHint _sometimes_ says when trying to declare variables with a name that already is a property of `window` (e.g. `name`, `status`, `length`, etc.). While it’s correct that that code doesn’t depend on order, it still depends on function-nesting.

Comment: @Xufox — That is not what it happening, and it does not depend on function nesting. See the accepted answer on the duplicate question which explains with screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `click()` exists in the narrower scope so that is what getting called here. [See these MDN docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Rename it to something else and your code will work.

```js
function clickButton1(val){
  console.log('val = ' + val);
  document.getElementById('button1').value = "X";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button1" onclick="clickButton1('button1 ')" />
```

Comment: `click` is not a reserved keyword. If it was, there would have been an errorat the line which attempted to declare the function.  It just already exists in a narrower scope. See the duplicate question.